# Assert that ActionBar item becomes visible after CAB is dismissed

Tags: android, testing, race-condition, instrumentation

I have the following two tests shown:

```
public void testOnClickCheckboxStartActionMode() {
    int index = 4;
    this.solo.clickOnCheckBox(index);
    Assert.assertTrue(this.solo.waitForView(R.id.delete_menu));
}

public void testOnClickCheckboxStopActionMode() {
    this.testOnClickCheckboxStartActionMode();

    int index = 4;
    this.solo.clickOnCheckBox(index);
    View addMenu = this.activity.findViewById(R.id.add_menu);
    Assert.assertNotNull(addMenu);
    Assert.assertTrue(addMenu.isShown());
}
```

The first checks that my ActionMode is correctly started when an item in my ListView is checked. The second checks that the ActionMode stops after unchecking the ListView item. The problem is that `testOnClickCheckboxStopActionMode()` fails on the line `Assert.assertTrue(addMenu.isShown());`. I can manually verify the correct behavior in my app, so the test seems to be broken. I believe the problem is that this assertion occurs before the UI thread has a chance to remove the CAB and restore the regular ActionBar.

I have tried `Instrumentation.runOnMainSync()` in order to synchronize my test with the UI thread:

```
    this.inst.runOnMainSync(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            View addMenu = activity.findViewById(R.id.add_menu);
            Assert.assertNotNull(addMenu);
            Assert.assertTrue(addMenu.isShown());
        }
    });
```

It still fails at the same assertion. Worse, the entire test suite stops, rather than simply signaling a failed test and continuing with the next one, because the `AssertionFailedError` is thrown on a separate thread.

How do I properly synchronize with the main thread in order to verify that the `ActionBar` menu items are indeed visible at the end of my tests?

Comment: No direct idea, but I'd look at how Robotium implemented `waitForView()` and see specifically how they are doing the "wait" bit.

Comment: @CommonsWare better yet I should just call solo.waitForView(). IIRC I had that in there before this set of changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix the problem by inserting a call to `Solo.waitForView()`:

```
public void testOnClickCheckboxStopActionMode() {
    this.testOnClickCheckboxStartActionMode();

    int index = 4;
    this.solo.clickOnCheckBox(index);

    // Added this call:
    Assert.assertTrue(this.solo.waitForView(R.id.add_menu));
    View addMenu = ButterKnife.findById(this.activity, R.id.add_menu);
    Assert.assertNotNull(addMenu);
    Assert.assertTrue(addMenu.isShown());
}
```

Strangely, I had originally tried modifying this test with `waitForView()` while fixing a bug. However, alone it didn't cause the test to fail in the presence of the bug. On the other hand, `addMenu.isShown()` didn't pass after the bug was fixed. Apparently a combination of both is required for this test to be correct.